# Skip download of required packages from 3rd party package

Tags: symfony, composer-php

We already have in our project "jquery" and "bootstrap" (we downloaded this libs along time a go and are incorporated to our project already, but not via composer) and we are trying to install via composer another package that requires us to have jquery and bootstrap like we show in the code below.

The question is, how we can skip this requirements to avoid having duplicated libraries in our project?

```
"require": {
   "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
   "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
   "leafo/lessphp": "0.3.*",
   "twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.*",
   "components/jquery": "1.*",
   "ptachoire/cssembed": "v1.0.0"
},
```

We are talking about a Symfony2 project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install this packages via composer, and reorganize your code for using bootstrap from `vendor` dir. I think, it's a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is we are using another version of bootstrap (2.0.*) and despite of the required 2.3.* version, it's working for us. We can't upgrade it for now :(

Comment: So if I understood right, on `2.0.*` your required 3th party package is not work correct, isn't it? So you need also to install `2.3.* ` and there is no another way

Comment: or pick a tag of your 3rd party package that is compatible / requires bootstrap `2.0.*`

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning that with our actual version 2.0.2 of bootstrap, this package works fine for us. Everything is working fine, the only problem is that we don't need this "twbs/bootstrap" and "components/jquery" to be installed aswell (because we already have it but not via composer way)

Comment: Then try to remove `"twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.*",
   "components/jquery": "1.*",` lines and then include this libs manually directly in code. But it's not a good practice.